# A class with a mutable variable. API token

Tags: python, api

I am trying to create an API client, but the problem is that the token changes every hour.
I want to create a class that contains a "token" variable that should change every hour.

The idea is to get a token when first run the script, create this object and use it.

I have a function that successfully receives a new token on execution.

```py
class AccessToken:
    def __init__(self):
        self.token = get_new_access_token()

    def new_token(self):
        self.token = get_new_access_token()
        print(self.token)

    while True:
        time.sleep(3600)
        new_token()
```

```py
def get_new_access_token():
    body = {"client_id": config.ESPORT_ID,
            "client_secret": config.ESPORT_SECRET_KEY_API
    }
    resp = requests.post(f'https://.........../oauth/token', json=body)
    return resp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to record when the token was made, and compare timestamp to see if token is valid.

```
class AccessToken:
    TOKEN_TTL = 60 * 60 - 60 (`-60`: buffer)

    def __init__(self):
        self.new_token()

    def refresh_token(self):
        self.token = get_new_access_token()
        self.token_gen_time = time.time()  # When token was made

    def get_token(self):
        if time.time() > self.token_gen_time + self.TOKEN_TTL:
            # token can be expired.
            self.refresh_token()
        return self.token


access_token = AccessToken()
while True:
    time.sleep(5)
    token = access_token.get_token()
    # do something with token
```

Comment: Did I understand correctly, that in such an implementation we do not need the while loop?

Comment: @Denis, I thought `while` in the question was part of logic. ;)

Comment: no, this is my attempt at implementing the logic to request a new token every hour.
The challenge is simply to get a new key every hour.
And give it to fictions that need a token.And thanks for the help. I will test your version. I will write about the results.

Answer (score 0):

```py
class AccessToken:
    TOKEN_TTL = 60 * 60 - 60

    def __init__(self):
        self.token = get_new_access_token()
        self.token_gen_time = time.time()

    def refresh_token(self):
        self.token = get_new_access_token()
        self.token_gen_time = time.time()  # When token was made

    def get_token(self):
        if time.time() > self.token_gen_time + self.TOKEN_TTL:
            # token can be expired.
            self.refresh_token()
        return self.token
```